# R matrix summing columns vector

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vector

I have a vector and a matrix as follows

```
vec=c(1,1,1,5,5,7)
mat1=matrix(runif(10*length(vec)),nrow=10)
```

I want to create a new matrix mat2 from mat1.

```
mat2 will have number of columns = distinct elements in vec
1st column of mat2 will be summation of columns of mat1 where vec has value 1 (in this case column 1 to 3)
2nd column of mat2 will be summation of columns of mat1 where vec has value 5 (in this case column 4 to 5)
3rd column of mat2 will be summation of columns of mat1 where vec has value 7 (in this case column 6 to 6)
```

vec is not going to have a fix number of elements and I have provided just an example above. vec is going to have elements in ascending order and vec is going to have integer elements only

I thought about writing a for loop but I am struggling as vec could have any number of elements.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rowSums` function to sum a subset of the columns of a matrix (in your case, those corresponding to a particular value in your vector). To iterate over all possible values of your vector, you could use `sapply`:

```
# Reproducible dataset
set.seed(144)
mat1=matrix(runif(10*length(vec)),nrow=10)

sapply(unique(vec), function(x) rowSums(mat1[,vec == x,drop=F]))
#            [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
#  [1,] 0.8908481 1.1987764 0.200360078
#  [2,] 0.9143586 0.4320678 0.617083644
#  [3,] 1.8743282 0.8998081 0.463207436
#  [4,] 1.2169977 1.9502429 0.116956239
#  [5,] 0.7510266 0.6792186 0.249493016
#  [6,] 1.5971054 0.8156898 0.860322422
#  [7,] 0.7507476 0.7435681 0.976815212
#  [8,] 1.7472541 0.5949144 0.169615928
#  [9,] 1.5338936 0.7695170 0.859721852
# [10,] 1.3822168 1.3014881 0.007783816
```

The `drop=F` argument makes sure your subsets of `mat1` remain matrices even if you select a single column.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, with an overlooked function, using josilber's "mat1":

```
t(rowsum(t(mat1), vec))
#              1         5           7
# [1,] 0.8908481 1.1987764 0.200360078
# [2,] 0.9143586 0.4320678 0.617083644
# [3,] 1.8743282 0.8998081 0.463207436
# [4,] 1.2169977 1.9502429 0.116956239
# [5,] 0.7510266 0.6792186 0.249493016
# [6,] 1.5971054 0.8156898 0.860322422
# [7,] 0.7507476 0.7435681 0.976815212
# [8,] 1.7472541 0.5949144 0.169615928
# [9,] 1.5338936 0.7695170 0.859721852
#[10,] 1.3822168 1.3014881 0.007783816
```